# trying to make some code dynamic using some custom coldfuison

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

Hi I have this code in html

```
<div class="rating-star-wrap"> <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="star-rating active"> 
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.788 3.21c.448-1.077 1.976-1.077 2.424 0l2.082 5.007 5.404.433c1.164.093 1.636 1.545.749 2.305l-4.117 3.527 1.257 5.273c.271 1.136-.964 2.033-1.96 1.425L12 18.354 7.373 21.18c-.996.608-2.231-.29-1.96-1.425l1.257-5.273-4.117-3.527c-.887-.76-.415-2.212.749-2.305l5.404-.433 2.082-5.006z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path> 
    </svg> </span> <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="star-rating active"> 
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.788 3.21c.448-1.077 1.976-1.077 2.424 0l2.082 5.007 5.404.433c1.164.093 1.636 1.545.749 2.305l-4.117 3.527 1.257 5.273c.271 1.136-.964 2.033-1.96 1.425L12 18.354 7.373 21.18c-.996.608-2.231-.29-1.96-1.425l1.257-5.273-4.117-3.527c-.887-.76-.415-2.212.749-2.305l5.404-.433 2.082-5.006z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path> 
    </svg> </span> <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="star-rating active"> 
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.788 3.21c.448-1.077 1.976-1.077 2.424 0l2.082 5.007 5.404.433c1.164.093 1.636 1.545.749 2.305l-4.117 3.527 1.257 5.273c.271 1.136-.964 2.033-1.96 1.425L12 18.354 7.373 21.18c-.996.608-2.231-.29-1.96-1.425l1.257-5.273-4.117-3.527c-.887-.76-.415-2.212.749-2.305l5.404-.433 2.082-5.006z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path> 
    </svg> </span> <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="star-rating active"> 
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.788 3.21c.448-1.077 1.976-1.077 2.424 0l2.082 5.007 5.404.433c1.164.093 1.636 1.545.749 2.305l-4.117 3.527 1.257 5.273c.271 1.136-.964 2.033-1.96 1.425L12 18.354 7.373 21.18c-.996.608-2.231-.29-1.96-1.425l1.257-5.273-4.117-3.527c-.887-.76-.415-2.212.749-2.305l5.404-.433 2.082-5.006z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path> 
    </svg> </span> <span><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" class="star-rating"> 
    <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10.788 3.21c.448-1.077 1.976-1.077 2.424 0l2.082 5.007 5.404.433c1.164.093 1.636 1.545.749 2.305l-4.117 3.527 1.257 5.273c.271 1.136-.964 2.033-1.96 1.425L12 18.354 7.373 21.18c-.996.608-2.231-.29-1.96-1.425l1.257-5.273-4.117-3.527c-.887-.76-.415-2.212.749-2.305l5.404-.433 2.082-5.006z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path> 
    </svg> </span> 
</div>
```

where the purpose is that i am trying to use the above code basically dynamically based upon the ratings i get by the table data

what could be the best approach for dealing with this kind of code

[image]

that is the DB and if the division by 0, is not possible, so it should be 5 stars max, no more than 5, because that is maximum what my code does.

please guide how can i moved head with that code

the `unique_content_id` is the `productID` i have

Comment: Your question is not clear.  There is little if any resemblance between your query data and the html code.

Comment: You've got a 5-star rating widget and data that looks to be a vote counter. How are you translating votes to stars? Where does the division by 0 come in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the rating per record via SQL:

```
SELECT
    IF(
        (vote_up + vote_down) > 0,               -- prevent division by zero
        ((vote_up / (vote_up + vote_down)) * 5), -- 5 is the maximum of stars
        0                                        -- no votes yet
    )
    AS starRating
```

You can then loop over your query result from this `SELECT` and print stars like this:

```
<cfquery name="ratings" datasource="...">

    SELECT
        ...

</cfquery>

<cfset svgFullStar  = '<svg>...</svg>'>
<cfset svgEmptyStar = '<svg>...</svg>'>

<cfloop query="ratings">

    <cfset fullStars  = round(ratings.starRating)> <!--- or ROUND() in the SQL SELECT --->
    <cfset emptyStars = (5 - fullStars)>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="product">
            #encodeForHtml(ratings.unique_content_id)#
        </div>
        <div class="rating-star-wrap">
            #repeatString(svgFullStar,  fullStars)#
            #repeatString(svgEmptyStar, emptyStars)#
        </div>
    </div>

</cfloop>
```

That's the display logic for whole stars like 3/5.